# Actionscript3: Countdown number of ducks

Tags: actionscript-3

> Clouds,
>   ducks,
>   score
>   display
>   and
>   waves
>   should
>   each
>   have
>   a
>   class
>   to
>   govern
>   their
>   movement
>   and
>   behavior.
>
> When
>   ducks
>   are
>   clicked
>   on
>   they
>   are
>   “shot”
>   and
>   the
>   duck
>   is
>   removed
>   from
>   the
>   array
>   as
>   well
>   as
>   from
>   the
>   stage
>   (use
>   arrayName.splice()
>   for
>   this).
>   The
>   score
>   display
>   should
>   count
>   down
>   as
>   this
>   occurs.
>
> The
>   number
>   of
>   ducks
>   left
>   should
>   be
>   a
>   property
>   within
>   the
>   Score
>   Display’s
>   class
>   and
>   adjusted
>   by
>   Main
>   when
>   the
>   ducks
>   are
>   shot.
>
> When
>   all
>   the
>   ducks
>   are
>   “shot”
>   the
>   game
>   should
>   animate
>   the
>   “you
>   win”
>   message.
>   This
>   can
>   be
>   done
>   by
>   adding
>   and
>   removing
>   event
>   listeners
>   that
>   associate
>   an
>   ENTER
>   FRAME
>   event
>   with
>   an
>   animating
>   function.
>   (This
>   is
>   worth
>   only,
>   so
>   leave
>   it
>   for
>   last).
>
> When
>   the
>   ducks
>   are
>   “shot”
>   the
>   waves
>   and
>   clouds
>   should
>   also
>   be
>   removed
>   from
>   view
>   AND
>   from
>   their
>   respective
>   arrays.
>
> Game
>   should
>   reset
>   after
>   player
>   has
>   won
>   or
>   lost
>   many
>   times.
>   (not
>   just
>   once)

I have most of this done, I'm just having trouble with the scoreboard. Any tips on how to reset everything, and code the you win sign would help too.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;

[SWF(width="800", height="600", backgroundColor="#E6FCFF")]

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var _sittingDucks:Array = []; //always set your arrays with [] at the top
    public var _scoreDisplay:TextField


    public function Main()
    {
        //adding the background, and positioning it
        var background:Background = new Background();
        this.addChild(background);
        background.x = 30;
        background.y = 100;

        for(var i:uint = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //adding the first cloud, and positioning it
            var clouds:Clouds = new Clouds();
            this.addChild(clouds);
            clouds.x = 130 + Math.random() * 600; //130 to 730
            clouds.y = 230;
            clouds.speedX = Math.random() * 3;
            clouds.width = clouds.height = 200 * Math.random()//randomly changes the clouds demensions
        }   

        var waves:Waves = new Waves();
        this.addChild(waves);
        waves.x = 0;
        waves.y = 510;
        waves.speedX = Math.random() * 3;


        for(var j:uint = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            var ducks:Ducks = new Ducks();
            this.addChild(ducks);
            ducks.x = 100 + j * 100;
            ducks.y = 475;
            _sittingDucks.push(ducks);
            ducks.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ducksDestroy);
        }

        var waves2:Waves = new Waves();
        this.addChild(waves2);
        waves2.x = 0;
        waves2.y = 520;
        waves2.speedX = Math.random() * 3;

        var setting:ForeGround = new ForeGround();
        this.addChild(setting);
        setting.x = 0;
        setting.y = 50;
        setting.width = 920;

        var board:ScoreDisplay = new ScoreDisplay();
        this.addChild(board);
        board.x = 570;
        board.y = 35;

    }
    private function ducksDestroy(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //store the crow we clicked on in a new array
        var clickedDuck:Ducks = Ducks(event.currentTarget);

        //remove it from the crows array
        //find the address of the crow we are removing
        var index:uint = _sittingDucks.indexOf(clickedDuck);

        //remove it from the array with splice
        _sittingDucks.splice(index, 1);

        //remove it from my document's display list
        this.removeChild(clickedDuck);
    }
}


import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import ScoreDisplayBase; // always import the classes you are using

public class ScoreDisplay extends ScoreDisplayBase
{
    private var txt:TextField; // where is it initialized?
    private var score:uint = 0;

    public function ScoreDisplay()
    {
        super(); // do you init txt here?
    }

    public function scoreUpdate():void
    {
        score += 10; // ok, so I suppose that your score does not represent the remaining ducks as you said, just only a score
        txt.text = score.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm creating a small game for my son

Comment: Dropbox is blocked by my (and I'm sure others) corp nets, may want to provide relevant code in the question, or find a different place to link from.

Comment: this site acts weird when i place code into the box. what would be the best option or site?

Comment: Add code to the box in this site. Highlight it. Press the `{}` button on the top of the input box. Or, if you'd rather not, codepad works for most people.

Comment: i'm just trying to get the score board to display how many ducks are left after being shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aaaalrighty:

1. You do want to create the TextField txt in ScoreDisplay's constructor. Instantiate it, set its text to initial score (0), and `addChild(txt)`.
2. In order to set the score later, we'll need a way to reference the display.

   ```
   //you want a reference to the ScoreDisplay, not this
   public var _scoreDisplay:TextField //no
   public var _scoreDisplay:ScoreDisplay //yes
   ```

   and when you create it in the Main constructor, we need to keep a reference.

   ```
   _scoreDisplay = :ScoreDisplay = new ScoreDisplay();
   this.addChild(_scoreDisplay );
   _scoreDisplay .x = 570;
   _scoreDisplay .y = 35;
   ```
3. If you want to be able to reset the game, I would recommend taking the duck creation and placing it in a method outside the Main class' constructor. You should also create a 'reset' function that sets the score (and the display) to 0 in ScoreDisplay.

   ```
   private function spawnDucks() {
       for(var j:uint = 0; j < 8; j++)
       {
           var ducks:Ducks = new Ducks();
           this.addChild(ducks);
           ducks.x = 100 + j * 100;
           ducks.y = 475;
           _sittingDucks.push(ducks);
           ducks.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ducksDestroy);
       }
   }
   ```

   and then you call it in the constructor, and can call it again when you need to reset the game.
4. `ducksDestroy(event:MouseEvent)` is going to be where you want to recalculate the score, check if you've won, show a message, and reset the game. You'll need some kind of popup to display, [here](http://activeden.net/item/dynamic-as3-popup-class/98559) is a decent one if you don't know where to get started at with that.

   ```
   private function ducksDestroy(event:MouseEvent):void
   {
       //store the crow we clicked on in a new array
       var clickedDuck:Ducks = Ducks(event.currentTarget);

       //remove it from the crows array
       //find the address of the crow we are removing
       var index:uint = _sittingDucks.indexOf(clickedDuck);

       //remove it from the array with splice
       _sittingDucks.splice(index, 1);

       //remove it from my document's display list
       this.removeChild(clickedDuck);

       //update the score
       _scoreDisplay.scoreUpdate();

       //Check if all the ducks are gone
       if (_sittingDucks.length == 0) {
           //All the ducks are dead, we've won the game!

           //create some kind of popup to display.
           //add it to the screen, have some form
           //of button (or a timer) take it away

           //whatever takes the popup away, have it call 'reset'

       }
   }

   private function reset():void
   {
       //write a reset method to clear the score
       _scoreDisplay.reset(); 

       //create some ducks and you're ready to go!
       spawnDucks();
   }
   ```

Comment: i'm going to try this and let you know. i did want to tell you that the countdown board text is set to dynamic, so if that changes everything then would i still create a textfield in the board class?

Comment: @user1276896 dynamic only means that it can be given properties that weren't declared. Like the basic Object class.

Comment: sorry i haven't replied in awhile been working on this all day. the scoring works. thanks for the help also. i'm trying to get a button to now reset the whole game.